# Reading Echo from .cmd file output using Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am attempting to run a .cmd file from the command line using Qt.  I need to be able to start the .cmd file and then I need to read the line output to be able to interpret whether it succeeded or not.

My .cmd file that I am testing with is as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO myBat Started.
ECHO myBat Ended.
```

Running this from the command line gives me "myBat Started." followed by "myBat Ended."

Below is my code that I am attempting to read the data output from.

```
QString batName = "/path/to/*.cmd";
QProcess p;
qDebug() << "starting command";
p.start("cmd.exe", QStringList() << batName);
if (p.waitForStarted()){
   qDebug() << "cmd started";
   p.waitForFinished();
   qDebug() << p.readAllStandardOutput();
} else {
    qDebug() << "Failed to start";
}
```

When I run this, I get "starting command", followed by "cmd started", followed by "".  So I am opening the console correctly (I think), it finishes, but then I am not getting any of the data output.

What do I need to change to read the command line output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `/C` switch to the `cmd` command so that `cmd.exe` terminates after executing your batch file.

i.e., this line:

```
p.start("cmd.exe", QStringList() << batName);
```

should look like this:

```
p.start("cmd.exe", QStringList() << "/C" << batName);
```

you can even start your batch file directly, like this:

```
p.start(batName);
```

P.S. please don't use `waitFor*` functions if your code is being executed in the GUI thread, use signals/slots instead. . .